# Good way to sort object by date property in anonymous type?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var resultArticles = from a in articleItems 

select new
{
   Title = a.Title, 
   ArticleDate = a[Constants.FieldNames.ArticleStartDate] != null ?
     ((DateTime)a[Constants.FieldNames.ArticleStartDate]).ToString(Constants.Date.Format): string.Empty,
   ByLine = a[Constants.FieldNames.Byline],
   FileRef = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Url, a.Url)
};

var sortedArticles = resultArticles.OrderBy(a => a.ArticleDate).ToList();

rptArticles.DataSource = sortedArticles;
rptArticles.DataBind();
```

I guess there must be a better way to sort/order here because if I have the dates (dd/mm/yyy)

```
12.01.2011
11.02.2011
10.02.2011
13.01.2011
08.02.2011
```

it only sorts by the day and don't take the month into consideration so the result in sortedArticles is as follows:

```
08.01.2011
10.02.2011
11.02.2011
12.01.2011
13.01.2011
```

I obviously want to display the latest article first, i.e. `11.02.2011`

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you order `var resultArticles = from a in articleItems` and then create your anonymous object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your Select, you're calling `ToString` on your date field.  As a result ArticleDate is being projected as a **string**. This is why it's not sorting correctly.

Projecting the ArticleDate as a nullable Date is probably your best bet

```
var resultArticles = from a in articleItems 
select new
{
   Title = a.Title, 
   ArticleDate = a[Constants.FieldNames.ArticleStartDate] != null ?
     ((DateTime)a[Constants.FieldNames.ArticleStartDate]) : default(DateTime?),
   ByLine = a[Constants.FieldNames.Byline],
   FileRef = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Url, a.Url)
};
```

Also, for something simple like this, you can use the more concise "dot notation"

```
var resultArticles = articleItems.Select(a => new { 
   Title = a.Title, 
   ArticleDate = a[Constants.FieldNames.ArticleStartDate] != null ?
     ((DateTime)a[Constants.FieldNames.ArticleStartDate]) : default(DateTime?),
   ByLine = a[Constants.FieldNames.Byline],
   FileRef = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.Url, a.Url)
};
```

At this point you can sort this collection by ArticleDate, which will be stored as a true Date, instead of a string

```
resultArticles.OrderBy(a => a.ArticleDate).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for this, I still need to present the date in the custom format dd.mm.yyyy though - that's the only reason why I first tried with .ToString()

Comment: @user997685 - you can **present** it however you need, you just need to **store** it as an actual date.

Comment: @user997685 - so whenever you go to display it to the user, **that's** when you call ToString(CustomFormat).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax

```
var q = from el in dataSource orderby el.SortField select new { 
    //your projection
};
```

The point here is to sort during the selection in one query.

**Edit**

By using this statement you sort by actual DateTime and project string representation.